# Supress keras messages : (Const): /job/localhost/

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've made a custom layer in keras and testing it prints a slew of messages such as :

```
Const_4340: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_4341: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Const_4342: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
....
```

or

```
input_112: (Placeholder): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
noise0_74/random_uniform/shape: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
...
noise0_74/Const_3: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
noisy_layer_108/random_uniform/shape: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
noisy_layer_108/random_uniform/min: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
noisy_layer_108/random_uniform/max: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
.....
Adam_89/iterations/Initializer/initial_value: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam_89/learning_rate/Initializer/initial_value: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam_89/beta_1/Initializer/initial_value: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam_89/beta_2/Initializer/initial_value: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Adam_89/decay/Initializer/initial_value: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
...
```

making it impossible to debug. 
What do they mean? How do I read them? Is there a way to suppress them? Or is there at least a workarround?

EDIT: here is more of the code:
the main script:

```
from noisy_net import *
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
from dqn_utilities import *
import logging

cwd = os.getcwd() 
path = cwd+"/models/space_invaders/"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

def save_model(agent):
    p = os.path.join(path, agent.name +"checkpoint.h5")
    agent.model.save(p)
    print("Model Saved")
    return

Agent = Agent_NoisyNet()

score_history = []

state = env.reset()
episode_reward = 0
episode = 0
try:
    for step in range(TOTAL_TR_STEPS):
        if step % 1000 == 0:
            print("Step no: " + str(step))

        action = Agent.predict_action(state)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        episode_reward += reward

        experience = (state, action, reward, next_state, done)
        Agent.memory.append(experience)

        if RENDER==True:
            env.render()

        _ = Agent.train()       

        Agent._update_target()

        state = next_state

        if done or step == TOTAL_TR_STEPS-1:
            score_history.append(episode_reward)
            state = env.reset()
            episode+=1
            avg_score = np.mean(score_history[-20:])
            print(f"At step: {step}")
            print('episode ', episode, 'score %.2f average score %2f' % \
                  (episode_reward, avg_score))
            score_history.append(episode_reward)
            episode_reward = 0

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    raise

env.close()
```

-The script that makes the network:

```
from Memory import ReplayMemory
from params import *
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
from NoisyLayer import NoisyLayer
import tensorflow as tf
from time import time

class Agent_NoisyNet():
    def __init__(self, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, action_size=ACTION_SPACE_SIZE,
                 memory_size=MEMORY_SIZE, duel_type=DUEL_TYPE, double=DOUBLE,
                 noise_type=NOISE_TYPE, conv_params=CONV_PARAMS, dense_params=DENSE_PARAMS, 
                 gamma=GAMMA, batch_size=MINIBATCH_SIZE, learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
                 name=NAME):
        self.state_shape = input_shape
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.memory_size = memory_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.gamma = gamma

        self.duel_type = duel_type
        self.double = double
        self.noise_type = noise_type

        self.model = self._create_network(conv_params, dense_params)
        self.target_model = self._create_network(conv_params, dense_params)

        self._update_target()

        self.memory = ReplayMemory(self.memory_size)
        self.name = name

    def total_update(self):
        self._update_target()

    def _update_target(self):
        self.target_model.set_weights((self.model.get_weights()))

    def _sample_noise_model(self, model):
        name = 'noise'
        noise_layers = [model.get_layer(index=index)\
                        for index in range(len(model.layers))\
                        if name in model.get_layer(index=index).name]
        for layer in noise_layers:
            layer.set_noise()

    def _create_network(self, conv_params, dense_params):
        inputs = Input(shape=self.state_shape)
        out = inputs

        for index, units in enumerate(dense_params):
            out = NoisyLayer(units=units, name=f'noise{index}', activation='relu')(out)

        outputs = NoisyLayer(units=self.action_size)(out)
        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
        opt = Adam(lr=self.learning_rate)
        model.compile(opt, loss='mean_squared_error')

        return model

    def train(self):
        if self.memory.size < MIN_REPLAY_MEMORY_SIZE:
            return None
        self._sample_noise_model(self.model)
        self._sample_noise_model(self.target_model)

        states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones = \
                    self.memory.sample(self.batch_size)

        p_Qs = self.model.predict(states)
        t_Qs = np.copy(p_Qs)
        index_range = np.arange(states.shape[0])
        t_Qs[index_range, actions] = self.bootstrap(rewards, next_states, dones)

        history = self.model.fit(states, t_Qs, batch_size=self.batch_size)

        return history.history["loss"]

    def bootstrap(self, rewards, next_states, dones):
        Qs = self.model.predict(next_states)
        actions = np.argmax(Qs, axis=-1)
        rows = np.arange(Qs.shape[0])
        return rewards + self.gamma * Qs[rows,actions]*(1-dones)

    def predict_action(self, state):
        self._sample_noise_model(self.model)
        state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)
        Qs = np.squeeze(self.model.predict(state))
        action = np.argmax(Qs)
        return action
```

-The custom layer class:

```
from params import *
from keras.layers import Layer, Multiply, Add, Dot, add, Dense
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from keras.activations import relu
from time import time
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import initializers
from math import sqrt

class NoisyLayer(Dense):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units # output_dimension
        self.noise_type = 'factorised'
        super(NoisyLayer, self).__init__(units,**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.state_shape = input_shape
        W = 1/sqrt(input_shape[1])
        B = SIGMA_0/sqrt(input_shape[1])
        self.weight_mu = self.add_weight(name='weight_mu', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.units),
                                      initializer=initializers.uniform(-W, W),
                                      trainable=True)
        self.weight_sigma = self.add_weight(name='weight_sigma', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.units),
                                      initializer=initializers.Constant(B),
                                      trainable=True)

        self.bias_mu = self.add_weight(name='bias_mu', 
                                      shape=(self.units,),
                                      initializer=initializers.uniform(-W, W),
                                      trainable=True)
        self.bias_sigma = self.add_weight(name='bias_sigma', 
                                      shape=(self.units,),
                                      initializer=initializers.Constant(B),
                                      trainable=True)
        self.eps_w, self.eps_b = None, None
        self.set_noise()
        self.bias = None
        self.built = True

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        WeightedInp = K.dot(input_tensor, 
                            self.weight_mu + self.weight_sigma * self.eps_w)
        bias = self.bias_mu + self.bias_sigma * self.eps_b
        return self.activation(K.bias_add(WeightedInp, bias))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.units)

    def _sample_noise(self):
        t1= time()
        if self.noise_type == 'factorised':
            eps_w_temp = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(max(self.state_shape[1], self.units)))
            eps_b = np.random.normal(0,1, size=self.units)
            eps_w = np.zeros((self.state_shape[1], self.units))
            f = lambda x : self._factor_function(x)

            for i, j in product(range(self.units),range(self.state_shape[1])):
                eps_w[j][i] = f(eps_b[i])*f(eps_w_temp[j])

            eps_b = self._factor_function(eps_b)            
        else:
            raise Exception("No known type for noisy layer, from _get_epsilon")
        print("*******************************************")
        print("Elapsed time for sample_noise: ",time()-t1)
        print("*******************************************")
        return eps_w, eps_b

    def set_noise(self):
        eps_w, eps_b = self._sample_noise()      
        self.eps_w = K.constant(eps_w)
        self.eps_b = K.constant(eps_b)

    def _factor_function(self, x):
        return np.sign(x)*np.sqrt(np.abs(x))
```

--And a bunch of parameters and other classes:

```
import gym
import numpy as np

STACK_SIZE = 4
max_width = 84
max_height = 84
INPUT_SHAPE = [max_height, max_width, STACK_SIZE]
GAME = "CartPole-v0"
env = gym.make(GAME)
INPUT_SHAPE = env.observation_space.shape
ACTION_SPACE_SIZE =  env.action_space.n
ACTION_SPACE = np.array(np.identity(ACTION_SPACE_SIZE, dtype=int).tolist())

LEARNING_RATE = 0.00025 # or 0.000001
GAMMA = 0.99
INITIAL_NO_OP = 30

UPDATE_TARGET_STEPS = 10000
TOTAL_TR_STEPS = 100000#50000000

MEMORY_SIZE = 100000
UPDATE_FREQ = 3
MINIBATCH_SIZE = 32
K_ = 3  # do the same predicted action every k_ steps

# EPSILON PARAMS
E_START = 1
E_STOP = 0.1    # over 1 mil steps, linearly
END_EPS_DECAY = 1000000

MIN_REPLAY_MEMORY_SIZE = 1000
RENDER = False

CONV_PARAMS = [] #for simple testing, without pixels
#CONV_PARAMS =  [(32, 8, 4), (64, 4, 2), (64, 3, 1)]
DENSE_PARAMS = [512]
#DENSE_PARAMS = [10]
VALUE_FC = 512
ADVANTAGE_FC = 512

DUEL_TYPE = "ave" # or "max" or 'naive'
DOUBLE = True # implement double or not boostrap method
NOISE_TYPE = 'factorised' # 'independent' # or 'factorised'
SIGMA_0 = 0.15
NAME = "NoisyNets_DQN"

......
import random
import numpy as np

MINIBATCH_SIZE = 64

class ReplayMemory():
    def __init__(self, max_size=10000):
        self.buffer = [None] * max_size
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.index = 0
        self.size = 0

    def append(self, obj):
        self.buffer[self.index] = obj
        self.size = min(self.size + 1, self.max_size)
        self.index = (self.index + 1) % self.max_size

    def sample(self, batch_size=MINIBATCH_SIZE):
        if self.size < batch_size:
            batch_size = self.size
        indices = random.sample(range(self.size), batch_size)
        exps = [self.buffer[i] for i in indices]
        states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones = zip(*exps)
        return [np.array(e) for e in [states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones]]
```

Comment: Presumably you have set `log_device_placement` to `True` somewhere. Without seeing the code it's difficult to say where, but grepping for that in your code would be a good start.

Comment: I don't though. Added the code just in case. Edit: explicitly setting to False though seems to fix it. Thanks, I didn't know of this option. Is there a guid for keras' logging?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, they don't import anything related to keras/tf. I did and nothing changed. Setting log_device_placement to False did the job though

Comment: Keras logging (during training) is usually done via callbacks to the `fit` method. I don't know if there's a good tensorflow guide/page describing this option, TF documentation is usually awful imo. The authoritative source for the session config flags are comments in the source code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L437, I think.